# how to export RUSTFLAGS in visual studio code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, rust

I want to export `RUSTFLAGS='-L /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/15.2/lib'` in visual studio code `Version: 1.77.3 (Universal)`, then I tried like this:

```
{
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug executable 'admin'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--bin=admin",
                    "--package=admin"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "admin",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env":{
                "RUSTFLAGS": "-L /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/15.2/lib",
            }
        }
```

but did not work, I also tried to add the `RUSTFLAGS='-L /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/15.2/lib'` in global `.zshrc`, then:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

and restart the visual studio code, still could not work. what should I do to make the visual studio code using the RUSTFLAGS environment? I also tried to add `.env` file in the root of project. and create environment like this:

```
RUSTFLAGS='-L /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/15.2/lib'
```

still could not work. this is all my libpq path in the system:

```
> sudo find / -name 'libpq.dylib' 2>&1 | grep -v 'Operation not permitted'|grep -v 'Not a directory'|grep -v "No such file or directory"
Password:
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/dolphin/anaconda3/pkgs/libpq-12.9-h1c9f633_3/lib/libpq.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/dolphin/anaconda3/lib/libpq.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/lib/libpq.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/libpq.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/libpq.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/lib/libpq.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.7/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.6_1/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/15.2/lib/libpq.dylib
/Users/dolphin/anaconda3/pkgs/libpq-12.9-h1c9f633_3/lib/libpq.dylib
/Users/dolphin/anaconda3/lib/libpq.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/lib/libpq.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/libpq.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/MacOSX-SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/libpq.dylib
/opt/homebrew/lib/libpq.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.7/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.6_1/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/15.2/lib/libpq.dylib
```

Comment: How are you launching VS Code? If you change the environment in zsh, you need to launch it from zsh.

Comment: I launch it from spotlight.

Comment: It seems odd that you'd need that specific setting in the first place. Why is Homebrew in such an unusual location? Can you symlink it back to where it's normally expected to be?

Comment: this config was the visual studio code generated. @PitaJ I could run the build command from terminal, but I also need to debugging the rust app in visual studio code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `env` section to `cargo` section:

```
{
    "type": "lldb",
    "request": "launch",
    "cargo": {
        "args": ["test", "--no-run", "--lib"],      // Cargo command line to build the debug target
                                                    // "args": ["build", "--bin=foo"] is another possibility
        // The rest are optional
        "env": { "RUSTFLAGS": "-Clinker=ld.mold" }, // Extra environment variables.
        "problemMatcher": "$rustc",                 // Problem matcher(s) to apply to cargo output.
        "filter": {                                 // Filter applied to compilation artifacts.
            "name": "mylib",
            "kind": "lib"
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb/blob/4cbb811eafa8e4f07f57fd74547d2ff6909f64ef/MANUAL.md?plain=1#L624